# How to add Stata programs in subdirectories?

Tags: stata

I'd like to add a directory containing `.ado` files to the ado-path. This directory contains several subdirectories, corresponding to different projects. The `.ado` files are in these subdirectories.

However, when I type `adopath + directory`, commands in the `.ado` files are not recognized by Stata. I need to enter `adopath + directory/subdirectory` for each subdirectory. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stata has a rule that in addition to the directories (etc.) explicitly named in the `adopath`, it will also look off those in subdirectories named by an individual letter for programs whose names begin with that letter.

Thus suppose you are invoking a command `whatever` and your named directories include `c:\ado\plus`. Stata's searches will include `c:\ado\plus\w` if that exists and a program file has not yet been found.

However, Stata doesn't promise to search in all subdirectories and it will pay attention to the initial letter of the program name.

Having `.ado` files specific to a project would best be accommodated by changing to the directory involved while working on that project. If you prefer not to do that, then you need to name specific directories fully if they don't match your `adopath` as extended by this single letter rule.

This is a matter of personal style, but I have never thought of any ados I wrote as specific to a particular project. Do-files yes, but not ados. But your project do-file might start with additions to the `adopath` and finish with reversing those.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I could not find anything in the Stata help. In my example, the different directories correspond to different personal "packages" (i.e. different thematic categories for the .ado files).

Comment: Correct. That is consistent with `help adopath` and the corresponding manual entry.